# Which to use for settings activity : preferences api or sharedpreferences?

Tags: android

I have a settings `activity` for users in my application. I manually add the changes to a `sharedpreferences` file ( simple delete , edit , add operations ). It works fine but just now i heard of preferences `activity`. Should i use it instead?

Comment: `PreferenceActivity` is already deprecated. So, go with `SharedPreference` only.

Answer (score 0):

`PreferenceActivity` and `Fragment` provide some advantages:

- Declare your UI through XML, where you can put preferences in categories, this makes your settings look and feel consistent with the system settings.
- Declaring preferences through xml associate each preference with a key and/or a default value, this saves you from writing the logic that handles such cases.

In the end you can achieve the same results with both approaches, but I recommend using the `Preferences Activity/Fragment` for the consistency with the system and avoiding boilerplate code or bugs that may appear from implementing the preferences yourself.

Check these tutorials for more info:
http://android-pro.blogspot.com.eg/search/label/SharedPreferences

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html